# Nginx reverse proxy replace part of location URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, header, oracle-apex

I have Oracle APEX and authentication server behind of Nginx proxy.

When I go to https://abc.mycompany.com/ords/f?p=105:1::::: I get redirect to auth server with `Location` header like this
`https://login.mycompany.com/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=APEX105&scope=openid+profile+email&redirect_uri=https://xyz.adb.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/apex_authentication.callback&state=blablalba`

How I can replace `xyz.adb.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloudapps.com` in the response to `abc.mycompany.com` ?

```
curl -I https://abc.mycompany.com/ords/f?p=105:1:::::
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://login.mycompany.com/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=APEX105&scope=openid+profile+email&redirect_uri=https://xyz.adb.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/apex_authentication.callback&state=blablalba
```

Comment: How do you connect to your backend from nginx? With a `proxy_pass` directive?

Comment: yes, using `proxy_pass https://xyz.adb.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try within the same `location` block:

```
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect ~^(.*[?&]redirect_uri=)([^&]*)(&.*|)$ $1<new_uri_here>$3;
```